# Is there any way of tracking votes to your answers after you've hit the rep cap?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, vote-count

I like to see which answers of mine are getting votes. Normally this is no trouble, since each vote is indicated by a corresponding change in reputation, and reputation changes are easily viewable. Once you've hit the reputation cap for the day, that connection is broken.

Today marks the first day that I've reached the rep cap early enough in the day to be a bother. Is there an alternate way of seeing recent votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The votes will still show up in your reputation view, but they won't have reputation gains associated with them.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-1114185687.png

Comment: +1 for FGITWing me. @Mark see http://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time