# Upvotes above your rep cap disappear from your Reputation view

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

Based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96192/is-there-any-way-of-tracking-votes-to-your-answers-after-youve-hit-the-rep-cap/96194#96194) to a previous question, I started monitoring my Reputation page. A couple of times I've seen an upvote appear with no reputation, only to have it disappear again when I refresh the page. Checking the answer reveals that it did indeed get an upvote, and the vote wasn't rescinded.

Update: there might be more conditions necessary to reproduce this bug. When I first noticed the bug it was on an upvote to the answer that was already at the top of the list with a reputation attached. I just received an upvote to another question and it is not disappearing, as expected.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the list of posts you have gotten reputation for, and seeing if there are any blank rep votes among them? If you get blank votes on a post, they'll be collapsed alongside the actual rep-providing ones.

Comment: @GraceNote I think that the problem is only in the "by time" view, where it appears to only be showing distinct vote-types rolled up into a single entry, regardless of whether they were separated by events on other posts in that time frame. I'm not sure if that's the expected behaviour or not, though.

Comment: @Grace Note, the list is already expanded for the day and I don't see any buttons to expand it further. Consecutive votes for the same answer appear to be consolidated, even if one vote gives you rep and the next does not.

Comment: @Tim Stone, thank you - I didn't realize there were other ways to view the tab other than "by time". Clicking on "by post" and expanding the post gives me what I expected.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128351/repcap-eating-up-events-in-repchange-bar/128357#comment350249_128357), this is done simply to reduce noise in the time-based sort:

> (logically) we walk those days chronologically if we have the same event type on the same post, we roll it up and the date used for that batch is the latest date in the batch. If there's an interruption (e.g. we get another event type, or another post) then that means a new batch, rinse, repeat. So we show everything chronologically in order, just rolled up to how have n of the same event on the same post in a row.

So if you got two up-votes in a row on the same post, one that granted reputation and one that didn't, you'd see only one entry in the list (but the little pop-up text seen upon hovering would spill the beans).