# Repcap eating up events in repchange bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, mobile-web

I usually rely on my rep number to see how well my pet posts are doing. In the event that I hit the cap, I obsessive-compulsively check the "rep by time" tab on my userpage. Also, I'm quite sure that rep eaten up by the system can be exchanged for free waffles.

Anyway, I do quite a lot of switching between the main site and full site, so I noticed this:

**Mobile site:**

[image]

**Main site (sorted by time) {*}:**
[image]

**Seems that there's a discrepancy between the number of waffle-eligible events out there.** Probably a bug. Otherwise part of balpha's (or maybe waffles') evil plan to keep all the waffles to himself--which they didn't push to the mobile build ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile simply has a full no-rollup chronological view that's different, it's completely intentional.  You can get this full no-rollup detail per-post by switching to the post view of your reputation and expanding that post on the full site - while it stays less spammy for no-change events on the time view.

*But* you can't change views on mobile, so we don't rollup at all...otherwise you have no avenue to get to that every-event detail level.

Comment: Alright... Since the time (desktop) view still shows a bit of the waffleposts, what's the criteria for a waffle post to be shown in time view?

Comment: @Manishearth - (logically) we walk those days chronologically (see what I did there?, I need sleep) if we have the same event type on the same post, we roll it up and the date used for that batch is the latest date in the batch.  If there's an interruption (e.g. we get another event type, or another post) then that means a new batch, rinse, repeat.  So we show everything chronologically in order, just rolled up to how have `n` of the same event on the same post in a row.

Comment: Ok, now everything makes sense. Thanks!